# Bound on Number of Faces of Non-Convex Polyhedra

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry

Suppose you have a polyhedra, not convex, and that the number of vertices is $N$. Furthermore, suppose that there are $O(N)$ edges.

Using the Euler Characteristic, $\chi$ , we have,

$F = E-V+ \chi = O(N) + \chi$

So, does there exist an upper bound on $\chi$ such that there are $O(N)$ faces?

Comment: The Euler characteristic of a connected surface in $\mathbb R^3$ is at most $2$.  Of course the number of connected components is at most the number of vertices.

Comment: I know I asked for an upper bound, but is there any lower bound as well?

Comment: Or does that depend on the genus of the polyhedron?